# Effectively loop through X, Y, and Z?

Tags: java, loops, coordinates

what I'm trying to do is effectively loop through the three planes in a 3-dimensional world based on a selection.

The only thing I can think of is the basic `for loop` (as shown):

```
for (int x = x1; x < x2; x++ ) {
    for (int y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
        for (int z = z1; z < z2; z++) {
...
```

The problem with this is if I have two coordinates marked `(59, 23, 72)` & `(59, 25, 89)`, the problem is that it checks for x1 (`59`) being less than x2 (`59`) which there isn't going to be any difference right there, so the rest of the loops aren't ran, even though there is a difference in their values.

I can think of two other approaches that I have not tried before, and I don't know how to:

- `Vector3i[]` - somehow establish the coordinates into the list, then loop through this.
- `int[][][]` - I have no experience with multi-dimensional arrays.

And still, with both of these methods, I can somehow see along the way I'm still going to have that "same value for [x, y, z]" problem.

How can I effectively loop through my selected region if two values of a plane are the same?

Comment: Can't you just use `<=` instead, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ChristianMann My apologies. This is out of my field of what I'm used to doing, and I've always found that `<=` was bad practice. It works, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by `Christian Mann` being to use `<=` instead of `<`. This is out of my ordinary comfort, so this never crossed my mind.

Thank you.